# Question on Distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If $T$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x^2 g)= 0$ for all $g \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}),$ then  there exists some constants $a$ and $b$ such that $T=a \delta +b \delta'.$ (I am defining derivative of a distribution as $T'(f)  =-T(f').$ I am stuck how to prove this.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and take $\rho \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $\{0\}.$ Then let $$\hat{f}(x) := f(x) - \left( f(0) + f'(0) x \right) \rho(x).$$ 
We have $\hat{f} \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\hat{f}(0) = 0$ and $\hat{f}'(0) = 0.$ Therefore, $\hat{f}(x) = \frac12 x^2 f''(0) + O(x^3)$ in a neighborhood of $x=0,$ so there exists $h \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{f}(x) = x^2 h(x).$ Therefore, by the assumption on $T$ we have $T(\hat{f}) = 0.$ Thus,
$$T(f) = T(\hat{f}) + f(0)\,T(\rho) + f'(0)\,T(x\rho) \\ = 0 + \delta(f)\,T(\rho) - \delta'(f)\,T(x\rho) \\ = a\,\delta(f) + b\,\delta'(f),$$
where $a = T(\rho)$ and $b = -T(x\rho).$

Comment: Thanks sir , I have some doubts ,  what does it means p(0)==1 on a nbhd of support f ? , secondly how you think that you have to take that type of function p and f hat functipn you define in D(R) , any help is appreciated , plz don't  downvote my post too , im new here .

Comment: Oops, it shouldn't say $\rho(0) \equiv 1$ but $\rho \equiv 1$. I've edited my post. Does it make sense to you now?

Comment: Also, it's enough if $\rho \equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $x=0.$ I've changed to that, too.

Comment: The idea is that we want to make a Maclaurin expansion of $f$ in a neighborhood of $0.$ But if we just wrote $f(x) = f(0) + x f'(0) + x^2 h(x)$ then the terms would not be in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}).$ We therefore use $\rho$ to fix this.

Comment: thx , f hat derivative - f'(x)- [(f(0)+f'(0) x) p'(x) + p(x) (f'(0) ] = f'(0)-[ f(0)p'(0) + f'(0) ] which is equal to  - f(0) p'(0) , if p is identically 1 in the nbhd of zero , then does it imply it's derivative at  0 at  0 ? in my opinion yes by applying definition of a derivative in limit form , am i right ??

Comment: You only need the product rule to find that $\hat{f}'(0) = 0.$

Comment: i have more questions , can u help me it's urgent , this site is not permitting me to ask different question , i have to wait , i have some questions and some doubts on distribution , plz any way u can help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90699/discussion-between-user534210-and-md2perpe).